Как вызвать приватный метод в публичном?
Есть приватный метод
class Class1 extends Class2
{
private function oneFunc()
{
$data = Data::factory()->create();
}

Как сделать так, чтобы этот объект, созданный в приватном методе, использовался в публичном методе того же класса?

Присвоить объект в свойство класса. Либо возвратить этот объект как результат вызова метода.

Надо прочитать основы по ООП и всё
